# Load Test with data binding in Cloud

Tags: data-binding, visual-studio-2017, load-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, I have created a web performance test that uses a .csv data source. The data source contains a list of URLs that I need to issue requests for. Running the web performance tests yields the expected result and each URL is requested successfully.

I added this test to a load test and ran this locally from visual studio, again it behaves as expected; all URLs are successfully requested.

Because I need to issue up to 500 requests in parallel, I'm attempting to run this load test in the cloud using visual studio online. I do have several load tests there running successfully though none that are data bound. The test does execute however, the binding of the URL in the request doesn't get replaced as expected. The test results show that the requested url is {{url}}. The test runs and doesn't indicate there were any errors.

The .csv data file is in the solution in a folder named datasource. The properties on the file for Copy To Output Directory is set to "Copy always".  I have even added the file to the deployment section of my testsettings file and checked "Enable deployment"

I have read conflicting information that indicates if this is supported or not. This post suggests that it is:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/05/14/binding-a-cloud-load-test-to-a-data-source/

While this page suggests that it isn't. But the context makes me wonder if that is true or not.

*"Q: What features not supported in the Visual Studio Web Test file?"*

*"A: At present this feature does not support Web Test plug-ins, data sources, and extraction rules. You must edit your Web Test file to remove these. We hope to add support for these features in future updates."*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/reference-qa

I'm wondering if anyone has done this (execute data-driven web performance test/load test on vsts) and has been successful? Or if this is not supported?

Comment: What part of the big FAQ page suggests that CSVs are not supported? There are words that SQL server is not supported. What folder contains the CSV and how is it deployed.

Comment: Q: What features not supported in the Visual Studio Web Test file?
A: At present this feature does not support Web Test plug-ins, data sources, and extraction rules. You must edit your Web Test file to remove these. We hope to add support for these features in future updates.

Comment: That is in the "Azure load testing" section. You are asking about cloud testing. I repeat: "What folder contains the CSV and how is it deployed?" Proper cloud based load testing supports plugins, extraction rules and data driving. Please [edit] your question to provide full details of your test and how you are trying to data drive it.

Comment: My sincere appologies. I didn't mean to be vague. My solution has a folder named DataSource. The Web Performance Test references the .csv file.

Comment: How does the statement *"My solution has a folder named DataSource. The Web Performance Test references the .csv file"* provide any useful information? This is your problem. You need to put some effort into providing the information that is needed for others to understand the problem.

Comment: You can run the test in the cloud via VS Enterprise, that way you can use data binding.